error with R and httr2 via curl::curl_fetch_memory(): ! OpenSSL/3.1.4: error:1C8000E9:Provider routines::ems not enabled
BLUF: Some (but not all) of my httr2 requests result in the error
Failed to perform HTTP request. Caused by error in `curl::curl_fetch_memory()`: ! OpenSSL/3.1.4: error:1C8000E9:Provider routines::ems not enabled

I've had a hard time finding information about this specific error or enabling the "EMS" routine. Is this likely to be a problem with my OpenSSL install, the server configuration, or something else?
Additional, possibly relevant, details:
I'm running an AWS EC2 instance with apache and a docker service, which hosts a docker container running shiny-server and my app. My app uses uses httr2 to call a web API. The dockerized app works fine when running it off of my local machine, but when running it off the EC2 instance I get a strange error:
Failed to perform HTTP request. Caused by error in `curl::curl_fetch_memory()`: ! OpenSSL/3.1.4: error:1C8000E9:Provider routines::ems not enabled

This error seems to only occur with specific URLs, others seem to work fine. I can also log in to the hosted instance and use curl directly to successfully make a call to one of the problematic URLs.
I'm trying to figure out if this problem has to do with my container's install or configuration of OpenSSL, something about my EC2 instance configuration, or something specific to shiny-server and/or httr2 in an AWS context.

Can you provide any sort of reproducible example? Like what EC2 image you are using and a specific URL that will trigger this error? Are errors specific to a given domain name/server? Or does it depend on the full URL? It seems most likely to be caused by your specific version of OpenSSL. You mention that directly using curl works, if you run curl -V, what libraries/versions is it linking to?

EMS stands for Extended Master Secret as defined in rfc7627. It is a widely deployed TLS extension. Any up-to-date TLS server should be able to support this (EMS was standardised in 2015). EMS is only relevant for TLSv1.2 (or below) and does not apply to TLSv1.3
This error occurs when OpenSSL has been configured to use the FIPS provider. FIPS compliance requires certain minimum standards. In this case it requires that if TLSv1.2 is in use then EMS must also be used.
This likely means that the server that you are connecting to (a) does not support TLSv1.3 and (b) also does does not support the TLS EMS extension.
Assuming you really need to talk to the server that you are trying to connect to the only real solutions are (1) disable the OpenSSL FIPS provider for this connection or (2) get the server operator to upgrade their server.

assuming the operator can't/won't upgrade the server... how would we go about disabling the OpenSSL FIPS provider for this connection? Is that something I would do inside the Docker container's configuration of OpenSSL, or something that we configure on the Apache server?

The OpenSSL FIPS provider is typically configured via the OpenSSL config file. The default config file is called openssl.cnf in the directory OPENSSLDIR, where OPENSSLDIR is the directory reported by openssl version -d. In the config file you are looking for the configuration of the providers (typically in a section called provider_sect). Documentation on the config file is here: https://docs.openssl.org/3.1/man5/config/#provider-configuration

Sometimes the config file can be somewhere else. Particularly if the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable has been set - in which case this overrides the default location. It is also possible for an application to override the default location for the config file, so unfortunately there is no guarantee that modifying the default config file will work for you. You'd need to check the docs for your stack.

I'm not familiar with the apache side configuration. It could be that your app is inheriting the FIPS config from the apache instance. A quick google search for apache and FIPS turns up this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html (see the SSLFIPS directive). So it might be that you can change this in the apache config, but I'm not sure.

I finally convinced them to upgrade the server openssl version from 1.0 to 1.1.1, and everything was fixed. Thank you! And yes, it turned out that FIPS was enabled on the server running the docker service, and so my app inherited that.

Below is the workaround we used before we were able to update the server's openssl version based on guidance in the accepted answer. We worked around the problem by making some changes to openssl.conf.
First, we replaced
openssl_conf = openssl_init

with
openssl_conf = default_conf

And then defined default_conf as follows:
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_section

[ssl_section]
system_default = system_default_section

[system_default_section]
providers = provider_sect
ssl_conf = ssl_module
MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = Cipher1:Cipher2:etc
Ciphersuites =

where CipherString values for Cipher1, Cipher2, etc. was the list of
ciphers that our apache server supports, e.g.
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:.... We got
the list of Ciphers by running the command openssl ciphers on the
Apache server. Defining an empty value for Ciphersuites essentially
disables TLS v1.3.
